# Debugging C++ code

Tags: c++, gdb

While running some code through gdb , I cam across this structure definition :

```
ptype spawnStmt
type = struct stmt {
    stmt *next;
    const char *stmtname;
    int lineNo;
    const char *filename;
    stmtType type;
    stmt::<anonymous union> s;
} *(var *, stmtlist *)
(gdb) p spawnStmt
$3 = {stmt *(var *, stmtlist *)} 0x80514f8 <spawnStmt>
```

Can someone please explain to me what this means - {stmt *(var *, stmtlist *)} 0x80514f8 .

My intention is to print the values of the elements in this structure.
What would be the correct syntax for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain to me what this means

`spawnStmt` is a function at address `0x80514f8`, taking `var*` and `stmtlist*` as parameters, and returning `struct stmt`.

> My intention is to print the values of the elements in this structure.

There is *no* "this structure" yet. You have to set a break point on `spawnStmt()`, `finish` from it, and only then can you print values of the elements (`finish` will actually print them for you).